# Extract all .img files from subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a directory with some subdirectories called *.data which contain a file named Ratio.img, a file called Ratio.hdr and a directory vector_data.

This is my setup:
dir:

```
-ABC.data/-Ratio.img
    /-Ratio.hdr
    /-vector_data

-DEF.data/-Ratio.img
    /-Ratio.hdr
    /-vector_data
```

I want a command-line solution to take the Ratio.img from each subdirectory, rename it to the name of the subdirectory (without .data) and move it to the directory itself.

I tried some stuff looking for .img images and move them, but I did not manage to include the renaming to the filename.

```
# Unfortunately all those .img file are named Ratio, so they ask me to overwrite, what I clearly do not want to.
FOR /R %G in ("*.img") DO Move "%G" "G:\GRD_TEst\Products"

#I tried Renaming the Ratio.img-files, since I think I could work with them even if they are named blah.data.img
FOR /D %G in ("*.data") DO Rename "G:\GRD_TEst\Products\"%G"\Ratio.img" "G:\GRD_TEst\Products\"%G"\"%G".img"


# I also tried some "nesting" of for loops, but this did not lead to the output I wanted, basically create the path to my Ratio.img-File

for /D %G in (.data) do 
    FOR /D %X in ("Ratio.img") DO echo %G\%X
```

I expect the output to be like
dir:

```
-ABC.img
-ABC.data/Ratio.hdr
    /vector_data
-DEF.img
-DEF.data/Ratio.hdr
    /vector_data
```

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I am reading stuff on SO for 3 years when I need it, I am really new to CMD-Stuff, but I will try to give you guys some code that I did and that did not do what I wanted it to :)

Comment: Just post what you have tried please, that will help to make the question on-topic at least.

Comment: I added the things I did so far, I tried a lot more without any results but syntax-error, but I can not provide them since I lost the overview.

Answer (score 0):

I might have found a solution (I have to reproduce my Ratio.img files since I did not make backup-copies :( )

```
`for /D %%G in ("*.data") do (
    FOR /D %%I in (Ratio.img) DO Rename G:\GRD_TEst\Products\%%G\%%I %%G.img
    FOR /D %%H in (Ratio.hdr) DO Rename G:\GRD_TEst\Products\%%G\%%H %%G.hdr)`
```

This did not work, it rename the files but I can not use them this way, they are not importable into ArcMap. Moving will be done in a 2nd step.

EDIT: After renaming the .hdr as well I can import the data in ArcMap finally, I updated the code-snippet above for my final solution.

Comment: you can do that all in one loop.. also doing `for /?` from `cmd` will show you how to expand on variables, for instance `%%~xH` will only display the extention of your file.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I am pretty sure it is doable in one loop and faster etc., but since I am not that good with cmd and it works fine for me, I will not spend more time than necessary on this minimal step inside of my project! Thanks for the help :)